# React - How to add onClick on a button in renderBody

Tags: reactjs

I am trying to implement OnClick inside the renderBody as shown in the code snippet. I need it to enable deletion of any record using it's id. I have the Table component handling table rows, data and pagination. The handleDelete function is inside the Main Component, Trials.
I need to implement a call to handleDelete function for every row I want to delete.

Adding itdirectly to renderBody gives an error "undefined handleDelete..." How can I add handleDelete function on every table row dynamically inside the renderBody?

```
import React from 'react'

const renderBody = (item, index) => (
  <tr key={index}>
    <td>{item.sn}</td>
    <td>{item.names}</td>
    <td>{item.gender}</td>
    <td>{item.regno}</td>
    <td>{item.email}</td>
    <td>{item.phone}</td>
    <td>
      <div className='flex-action'>
        <button
          className='btn-text'
          title={`View More Information`}
          onClick={ } //how to add an onClick function here
        ><i className="bx bx-list-ol" size={30} >Delete</i>
        </button>
      </div>
    </td>
  </tr>
)

const data = [
  {
    id: 1,
    name: "IphoneX",
    img:
      "https://didongviet.vn/pub/media/catalog/product//i/p/iphone-x-mau-xam-didongviet.jpg"
  },
  {
    id: 2,
    name: "Samsung Fold",
    img:
      "https://images.samsung.com/pk/smartphones/galaxy-z-fold3-5g/buy/zfold3_carousel_mainsinglekv_mo.jpg"
  },
  {
    id: 3,
    name: "Laptop Gaming",
    img:
      "https://cdn.techzones.vn/Data/Sites/1/News/3285/techzones-nhung-mau-laptop-gaming-choi-game-co-tan-nhiet-tot-nhat-tren-thi-truong.jpg"
  }
];
const Trials = () => {

  const [users, setUsers] = useState([])

  const [products, setProducts] = useState(data);
  //You can put all product information into diaglog
  const [dialog, setDialog] = useState({
    message: "",
    isLoading: false,
    //Update
    nameProduct: ""
  });
  const idProductRef = useRef();
  const handleDialog = (message, isLoading, nameProduct) => {
    setDialog({
      message,
      isLoading,
      //Update
      nameProduct
    });
  };

  const handleDelete = (id) => {
    //Update
    const index = data.findIndex((p) => p.id === id);

    handleDialog("Are you sure you want to delete?", true, data[index].names);
    idProductRef.current = id;
  };

  const areUSureDelete = (choose) => {
    if (choose) {
      setProducts(products.filter((p) => p.id !== idProductRef.current));
      handleDialog("", false);
    } else {
      handleDialog("", false);
    }
  };
  return (
    <div className="card__body">
      {
        users.length > 0 ? (
          <Table
            limit='20'
            headData={customerTableHead}
            renderHead={(item, index) => renderHead(item, index)}
            bodyData={users}
            renderBody={(item, index) => renderBody(item, index)}
          />
        ) :
          (
            <h3>No search results</h3>
          )
      }


      {
        dialog.isLoading && (
          <Dialog
            //Update
            nameProduct={dialog.nameProduct}
            onDialog={areUSureDelete}
            message={dialog.message}
          />
        )
      }
    </div>
  )
}

export default Trials
```

Comment: Pass it as an argument

Comment: Thank you for the feedback. Did you mean this ```` const renderBody = (item, index, handleDelete) ..... If yes, can it be introduced to the Table component?

Comment: Are you just asking how to pass a function to onClick? You can simply do `onClick={ () => console.log("I was clicked") }`.

Comment: Thank you @Nathan. I need to introduce the handleDelete function inside this component. But the function is in a different component, Trials,  as shown on the code snippet

Comment: You should change your title and focus of your question, in that case. But tl;dr; you can define `renderBody` *within* your `Trials` component instead of outside of it, and then you'll have access to `handleDelete`. Use a `useCallback` depending on `users` for performance.

Comment: You can do like @Nathan said and move the function into the component or you can just pass `handleDelete` to `renderBody` in the Table component: `renderBody={(item, index) => renderBody(item, index, handleDelete)}` (and make sure to add the argument to `renderBody` like you mentioned

Comment: Yeah, that works too, but I think it's needlessly complex here-- at that point you're passing something in order to get around it not being in scope, when you can just restructure and have it to be in scope to begin with :)  @JuliusPeterOdeke I posted an answer. Please update your question title though, to better reflect what you're asking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can move your `renderBody` definition *within* your `Trials` component, so that `handleDelete` is within scope. Additionally, use `useCallback` so that `renderBody` doesn't have to be constructed every time you render.

```
import React from 'react'

const data = [ REMOVED_FOR_COMPACTNESS ];

const Trials = () => {

  const [users, setUsers] = useState([])

  const [products, setProducts] = useState(data);
  //You can put all product information into diaglog
  const [dialog, setDialog] = useState({
    message: "",
    isLoading: false,
    //Update
    nameProduct: ""
  });
  const idProductRef = useRef();
  const handleDialog = (message, isLoading, nameProduct) => {
    setDialog({
      message,
      isLoading,
      //Update
      nameProduct
    });
  };

  const handleDelete = (id) => {
    //Update
    const index = data.findIndex((p) => p.id === id);

    handleDialog("Are you sure you want to delete?", true, data[index].names);
    idProductRef.current = id;
  };

  const areUSureDelete = (choose) => {
    if (choose) {
      setProducts(products.filter((p) => p.id !== idProductRef.current));
      handleDialog("", false);
    } else {
      handleDialog("", false);
    }
  };

  // will only create the callback whenever your users state changes,
  // for performance
  // fyi renaming "item" to "user" would be clearer
  const renderBody = useCallback((item, index) => (
    <tr key={index}>
      <td>{item.sn}</td>
      <td>{item.names}</td>
      <td>{item.gender}</td>
      <td>{item.regno}</td>
      <td>{item.email}</td>
      <td>{item.phone}</td>
      <td>
        <div className='flex-action'>
          <button
            className='btn-text'
            title={`View More Information`}
            // we now have access to handleDelete, since we're defined within the componenet
            onClick={ () => handleDelete(item.id) } 
          ><i className="bx bx-list-ol" size={30} >Delete</i>
          </button>
        </div>
      </td>
    </tr>
  ), [users])

  return (
    <div className="card__body">
      {
        users.length > 0 ? (
          <Table
            limit='20'
            headData={customerTableHead}
            renderHead={(item, index) => renderHead(item, index)}
            bodyData={users}
            renderBody={renderBody}
            // you can just pass the function, like above, since it
            // already takes 2 arguments. No need for an arrow function
            // old: renderBody={(item, index) => renderBody(item, index)}
          />
        ) :
          (
            <h3>No search results</h3>
          )
      }


      {
        dialog.isLoading && (
          <Dialog
            //Update
            nameProduct={dialog.nameProduct}
            onDialog={areUSureDelete}
            message={dialog.message}
          />
        )
      }
    </div>
  )
}

export default Trials
```